# Can't inject service in component in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a simple ionic 2 app.

**Created at service**

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AgendaPage } from '../pages/agenda/agenda';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public navCtrl: NavController) {}
}
```

**app.components.ts registration**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { Auth } from '../providers/auth';
import { Rides } from '../providers/rides';

import { AgendaPage } from '../pages/agenda/agenda';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [Auth, Rides]
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = LoginPage;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Minha Agenda', component: AgendaPage }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

**Trying to inject it into a component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Auth } from '../../providers/auth';

/*
  Generated class for the Agenda page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-agenda',
  templateUrl: 'agenda.html',
  providers: [Auth]
})
export class AgendaPage {

  openRides: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private auth: Auth) {}

}
```

I get the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for AgendaPage: (NavController,
>   NavParams, ?).

What I find strange is that I have a very similar other component where I can user the service without problems:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Auth } from '../../providers/auth';

/*
  Generated class for the Login page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  providers: [Auth]
})
export class LoginPage {

    email: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private auth: Auth) {}

    login() {

    }

}
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: Remove parameter from the constructor. Extra parameters are redundant in the code.

Comment: @Ramon, which parameter? Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I have not created an example for you. Keep waiting.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an authentication service, you probably don't need to provide it at the lower levels of abstraction.  It still needs to be imported to be used, but it doesn't need to be added to the providers[] in your lower tier components.

This may be causing the error, as for some reason it might not be able to provide an instance of Auth at that level of abstraction for whatever reason.  Notably, I try not to use constructors on my services -- that may be causing the issue as well (or both issues together.)

Comment: I took it out of the providers array in app.components.ts but kept it in the providers array inside my page component. The error disappeared. But now I can't use the service anymore inside of other services, because there I don't have a @Component decorator to set my providers...

Comment: @almo try doing the opposite and *only* providing it inside the app.component.

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me the same error: Can't resolve all parameters for AgendaPage: (NavController, NavParams, Rides, ?)..tricky...

Comment: This didn't quite solve my problem but made me look deeper how providers actually work. Thanks!

Comment: This is not the issue here

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is circular dependency. You are already importing the component in your service and want to inject the service in the same component. So angular does not know which to load first.
You need to look into **forwardref**.
In your component constructor,

```
constructor(...,@Inject(forwardref(()=>Auth))auth)
```

You might want to refer [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html) for more.